# How can I use LINQ to "prune" a dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary and a List of keys to remove from the dictionary. This is my implementation right now:

```
var keys = (from entry in etimes
            where Convert.ToInt64(entry.Value) < Convert.ToInt64(stime)
            select entry.Key).ToList();

foreach (var key in keys)
{
    etimes.Remove(key);
    count--;
}
```

Is there something I can do the eliminate the foreach loop?

Comment: By the way you didn't need the .ToList() foreach will work with any IEnumerable

Comment: LINQ is a query language, which can create new data by transforming existing data. It can not change existing data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var pruned = etimes.Where(entry => Convert.ToInt64(entry.Value) >= 
    Convert.ToInt64(stime)).ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, 
        entry => entry.Value);
```

This statement simply filters the dictionary using the LINQ `Where` function to select which items to *keep* rather than those to remove (which then requires further code, as you showed). The `ToDictionary` converts thwe `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` to the desire `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type, and is at least quite simple, if not terribly elegant or efficient due to the need to specify the two lambda expressions to select the key and value from a `KeyValuePair` (and then creating a new dictionary). Saying this, I don't really see it as a problem, especially if the dictionary is small and/or number of items being removed is large.

Comment: I wouldn't want to comment on the performance by the way - if you care about that, then test the two methods. I'm not sure your original solution using foreach would be *that much* faster.

Comment: I'm not worried about performance, there are only a few keys in the dictionary at any time. I'm just trying to get a better handle of LINQ. Thanks, this worked great.

Comment: This might be much more expensive than the simple for each loop because it will create a new dictionary. And I think it does not improve readability, too. So I would just stick with the for each loop and maybe move it to a (extension) method, but I see no win at all for the LINQ solution.

Comment: @Daniel: This is probably true, though if the number of items being removed is relatively large (or the dictionary is relatively small), then I doubt the difference in speed will be too significant. @scotty2012: Glad it works for you, anyway.

Comment: @Daniel: That may be true, but in my example, I'm creating an additional List<string> and running the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, performance or readability issues aside, couldn't this also be done something like the following:

```
<Extension> void itemDelete(List l, object item) {
    l.Remove(item)
}

var keys = (from entry in etimes
        where Convert.ToInt64(entry.Value) < Convert.ToInt64(stime)
        select entry.Key).ToList();

keys.foreach(itemDelete());
```

Forgive my coding, I'm not 100% certain of the exact syntax (especially in C#); consider that pseudo-code. 
Note the addition of the new function, and the **.foreach** function on the end of the LINQ query. 
I know this would be possible in VB, i assume C# has something similar... if not you could always write your own **.foreach** extension. 
It may or may not improve anything, but it's an idea.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a dumb question, but would you create this Extension method in a partial class? I'm still trying to come to grips with Extension methods and how you can use and create them.

Comment: @Jagd: This is no reason whatsoever to use a partial class. Recommended practice is to declare them on their own within a *static class* and group extension methods into static classes of similar functionality.

Comment: In VB you create them in Modules, so ... I'd say listen to Noldorin's Best Practices.